# i am trying to search a database for items from a particular location using laravel

Tags: laravel

i am trying to query a database and here is my approach, but yet i keep getting an undesired result and i'm not certain where the error is coming from, can someone please help me out. 
if the item feild is ommitted then it only searches through the states, but if the state field is ommitted it searches the items entire

```
function search(){

    //pr(Input::all(), true);

    //set the name and location...
    $nm = trim(Input::get('item_nm'));
    $lc = strtolower(trim(Input::get('item_lc')));

    if(!is_null($lc) && !is_null($nm)){

          $allitems = DB::table('items')                    
        ->join('users', 'items.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->join('profiles','items.user_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
        ->join('local_govs','profiles.lga_id', '=', 'local_govs.id')
        ->join('states','local_govs.state_id','=','states.id')
        ->join('item_codes', 'items.code_id', '=' , 'item_codes.id')

        ->Where('local_govs.lgas', 'like', '%'.$lc.'%')             
        ->orWhere('states.state', 'like', '%'.$lc.'%')  

        //query paramenters... here..
        ->where('items.prod_name', 'like', '%'.$nm.'%')
        ->orWhere('items.prod_want', 'like', '%'.$nm.'%')   

        //->andWhere('')
        //->Where('local_govs.lgas', 'like', '%'.$lc.'%')   

        ->orderBy('items.id', 'desc')
        ->get();

    }else{

        $allitems = DB::table('items')                  
        ->join('users', 'items.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->join('profiles','items.user_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
        ->join('local_govs','profiles.lga_id', '=', 'local_govs.id')
        ->join('states','local_govs.state_id','=','states.id')
        ->join('item_codes', 'items.code_id', '=' , 'item_codes.id')

        //query paramenters... here..
        ->where('items.prod_name', 'like', '%'.$nm.'%')
        ->orWhere('items.prod_want', 'like', '%'.$nm.'%')       
        ->orWhere('items.description', 'like', '%'.$nm.'%')

        ->orderBy('items.id', 'desc')
        ->get();

    }
    //pr($allitems, true);


    return View::make('pages.searchrst')
                ->with('sItems', $allitems )
                ->with('testimonys', $this->opinions)
                ->with('page_topic', 'Get your products listed, in 2 simple steps, relax and watch as we help you find those who need it most..');
}
```

i'm so lost right now, i'm trying to render a view at the end, but the results arent as expected.

Comment: If `$lc` isn't empty the query works fine and returns the correct result?

Comment: Try to change conditional like this:  if (!empty($lc) && !empty($nm)){ .. OR Try:  dd ($lc)  after your conditional if(!is_null($lc) && !is_null($nm)) so you can check if it work well or need change conditional.

Comment: sorry i'm just seeing this but thanks for your opinion, i'd try that and see, but my guess is that i'd still get the same result